# Error inside inject method

Tags: ruby

I am trying to learn the inject method. I thought I will just print elements as it calculates. But in the following code when I comment `print b` statement it works fine. But when I uncomment it, error occurs. What does that mean? The error occurs for `a+b` statement which is at `line number 4` mentioned in the error.

```
list = *(1..10)

list.inject(0) do |a, b|
  a + b
  print b
end
```

Error:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: `inject` works on ranges too: `(1..10).inject` etc is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
list.inject(0) do |a, b|
  print b
  a + b
end
#=> 12345678910=> 55
```

Explanation:

`inject` returns the cumulated value from previous iteration (`a`).

When you are printing `b` it is the return value of the iteration, thus `a` is `nil`. To solve it move the `print`ing above, so that `a` is still the return value of the iteration.