# Why do I get this Error in ruby: block in find_word_lengths': undefined method `[]=' for 3:Integer (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

the following code return this error:

> block in find_word_lengths': undefined method `[]=' for 3:Integer (NoMethodError)

```
animals = ['cat', 'horse', 'rabbit', 'deer']

def find_word_lengths(word_list)
  word_list.reduce(Hash.new()) do |result, animal|
    result[animal] = animal.length
  end 
end

puts find_word_lengths(animals)
```

Comment: You need to return the accumulator from the block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error inside inject method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173189/error-inside-inject-method) There is probably a better duplicate, but this is a bit hard to search for.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of the block is the accumulator value for the next iteration. That is how a *fold* works.

Assignments in Ruby evaluate to the right-hand side. So, in the first iteration of `reduce`, the block evaluates to `3` (the length of `'cat'`). Which means that in the second iteration of `reduce`, `result` is `3`, and you are essentially running

```ruby
3['horse'] = 5
# which is equivalent to
3.[]=('horse', 5)
```

Which is why you are getting the error message that the `Integer` `3` does not respond to the message `[]=`.

So, you need to make sure that your block always returns the value that you want to use for the accumulator in the next iteration. Something like this:

```ruby
word_list.reduce(Hash.new()) do |result, animal|
  result.tap {|result| result[animal] = animal.length }
end
```

This would be the obvious solution, although somewhat cheating.

```ruby
word_list.reduce(Hash.new()) do |result, animal|
  result.merge(animal => animal.length)
end
```

Would be more idiomatic.

However, when you want to fold into a mutable object, it makes more sense to use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead of [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). `each_with_object` ignores the result of the block, and simply passes the same object every time. Note that somewhat confusingly, the order of the block parameters is swapped in `each_with_object` compared to `reduce`.

```ruby
word_list.each_with_object(Hash.new()) do |animal, result|
  result[animal] = animal.length
end
```

But I guess the most idiomatic solution would be something like this:

```ruby
word_list.map {|word| [word, word.length] }.to_h
```

By the way, in Ruby, it is idiomatic to leave out the parentheses for the argument list if you are not passing any arguments, so `Hash.new()` should be `Hash.new` instead. Even more important than being idiomatic is to be consistent – confusingly, you leave out the parentheses for `animal.length`, but not for `Hash.new`

Even more idiomatically, you would use the `Hash` literal notation instead of the `Hash::new` method, i.e. you should use `{}` instead of `Hash.new`.

Comment: Thank you Jörg W Mittag you answered exactly what I am asking for.